# Javascript Object Creation with Index Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

I think I worded the title correctly, but...

Lets say I have an array:

> var arr = ['set1','set2','set3','set4','set5','set6'];

And i need to create an object that goes something like this:

```
'item(0).name' : '//some string'

'item(0).value(0)' : 'set1' // a.k.a arr[0] 

'item(0).value(1)' : 'set2' // a.k.a arr[0]

'item(0).value(2)' : 'set3' // a.k.a arr[0]
```

etc....

And then as it continues, it would also be possible to continue with **item(1).name** and all other properties thereafter would be **item(1).value(0), item(1).value(1), item(1).value(2), etc...**

I understand that there would be loops going through each array, and then using the arr index I could populate the values, however my trouble is centered around actually creating the obj properties '**item().name**' or '**item().value()**'. How would one go about accomplishing this?

***UPDATE***

This is actually part of an API call and has to look like it's written above as it is later extended in a data obj and passed over to a call. Hope that clears it up a little.

i.e.

> var data = {
>
> x : 0,
>
> y: 1,
>
> z: 6,
>
> 'item(0).name' : 'string',
>
> 'item(0).value(0)' : 'set1',
>
> 'item(0).value(1)' : 'set2',
>
> 'item(0).value(2)' : 'set3'
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

```
function demo(name, vals) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = vals || [];
}


var x = new demo('some string',  ['set1','set2','set3','set4','set5','set6']);

console.log(x.name);
console.log(x.value[0]); // etc...


var item = [x, new demo('some string2',  ['set1','set2','set3','set4','set5','set6'])];
console.log(item[0].value[1]);  // etc...
```

or create a wrapper like (if you don't want to index directly through [..]):

```
function demo2(name, vals) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = function(index) {
        return vals[index];
    }
}
```

hope this helps -ck

Answer (score 0):

Consider JSON-based structures instead. They're more self-describing then simple arrays. Properties can by pretty well arbitrary.

```
{
    "firstName": "Jason",
    "lastName": "Jones",
    "address": {
        "city": "San Francisco, CA",
        "zip": 94121,
        "address": "444 Columbus Ave"
    },
    "email": [
        "jason@sf.com",
        "sjones@adobe.com"
       ]
}
```

**Edit:** Your data (?)

```
var data = {
    'x':0,
    'y':1,
    'z':6,
    'name':'something',
    'item': [
        'value':'set1',
        'value':'set2',
        'value':'set3'      
     ]
}
```

Comment: What if the object has to look exactly like the description above? So that it can be extended into another data object and used with a request? I guess, the main question would be as to how I would go about creating an object that looks like item(0).name(0) and/or item(0).value(0++)..

Comment: I've added an example, I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I def worded this entire question incorrectly. I've included a fiddle to explain what i was looking for and I think I got it to work. And, I think I completely overcomplicated the entire approach as well. http://jsfiddle.net/pRNZJ/1/